# DJANGO: the combobox doesn't print in the textarea. Error in in html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

In the `home.html` page, i have a `combobox` and a `textarea`. I would like to achieve that if i click on an item in the combobox, using an (if) condition in `views.py`, i get the printout in the textarea. For example if I select "Red" then it must print "You chose red". Very simple. But there is something wrong with my code. Probably the problem is in the `home.html` file or in the `def home` function in the `views.py` file (i believe).

[image]

**Problem**: combobox(independent and NOT attached to a database) correctly browses items from list, but the condition doesn't apply. When I click on button, nothing happens.

How can I execute the condition correctly and print in the textarea when I select the combobox item? I'm new to django, can you show me an answer with the code please?

Post the code of `home.html`, `views.py` and `forms.py`. I hope someone can help me please. I think the problem is in the html! Thank you!

**home.html**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ combobox }}
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ textarea }}
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
colours = ["Red", "Blue", "Black", "Orange"]

@login_required
def home(request):

    #Combobox
    if request.method == "POST":
        combobox = SimpleCombobox(request.POST)
        if combobox.is_valid():
            print(combobox.cleaned_data)
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        combobox = SimpleCombobox()


    #TextArea
    if request.method == "POST":
        textarea = SimpleTextbox(request.POST)
        if textarea.is_valid():
            print(textarea.cleaned_data)
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        textarea = SimpleTextbox()


    message = ""
    picked = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        picked = request.form['colours']
        if picked == 'Red':
            message = "<<< You chose red"
        elif picked == 'Blue':
            message = "<<< You chose blue"
        elif picked == 'Black':
            message = "<<< You chose black"
        else:
            message = "<<< Oh no, you chose orange"

    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {"combobox": combobox, "textarea": textarea, "colours": colours, "chosen": picked, "message": message})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class SimpleCombobox(forms.Form):
    Col1 = 'Red'
    Col2 = 'Blue'
    Col3 = 'Black'
    Col4 = 'Orange'
      
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (Col1, u"Red"),
        (Col2, u"Blue"),
        (Col3, u"Black"),
        (Col4, u"Orange"),
    )
    cities = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)


class SimpleTextbox(forms.Form):
    coverletter = forms.CharField(required=False,
              widget=forms.Textarea(
                # rows and colums of the textarea
                attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
    

#LOGIN
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=65)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=65, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

**UPDATE ONLY FOR INFO**

For info, if it could help for the answer, I previously use this code `html` on `Flask` and it worked fine (I use the same combobox, textarea and condition but with Flask and it worked fine)

```
    <form name="Item_1" action="/user/home" method="POST">
      <select name="colours">
        {% for colour in colours %}
          {% if colour == chosen %}
           <option value="{{ colour }}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>
         {% else %}
           <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
          {% endif %}     
        {% endfor %}     
     </select>
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
    
  <form action = "/result" method = "POST">
    <input type="text" name="result" value="{{ message }}" />
  </form>
```

Comment: PLZ add code of form and model

Comment: I think you want like this...

https://ibb.co/RvsDsYT

Comment: @Mahammadhusain kadiwala I've updated the question with forms.py. I don't have model.py, I don't need it. The combobox does not use the database. Yes, I want to get what you showed me. Can you write me an answer with the code? Thank you

Comment: I'll put code tomorrow morning

Comment: the python forms are static, they are rendered on the server side. To be able to make a form dynamic at the client, it need to have some javascript code in the html to perform the action you want.
you need an onchange='js-function()' action on the drop down, and then have that function interact with the textarea. you usually want an id on the text area to then be able to look it up with a window.getElementById function, and update the 'text' field of that object

Comment: @MrE I don't think I need Javascript. I ran the same code as in the question with Flask and was not using Javascript. With Flask the same code (the code in my question) ran fine and the combobox printed to the textbox fine. The only difference was that there was an if in the html, but I didn't use Javascript. Javascript certainly helps and you said right in the comment, you're right, but I think it's possible to do it even without Javascript (like I did with Flask)

Comment: ok, so you're doing a round trip to the server to validate the submit. Your question is not very clear on that. in your code logic, you check if it is a POST, and if so print the combo box, the second check for POST never runs since it already returned on the first IF. you should put everyting that relates to the check for a POST under the same section, and if not then ...

Comment: @MrE I apologize if my question is not clear. I updated the question by including the html code I used in Flask as well. I would just like to print in the textarea (no Javascript). If I've done something wrong in the code, the reason is because I'm new to Django. Could you help me and show me an answer how I can fix the problem? It's just a simple (if) condition. Thank you

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala I am waiting for your kind solution. Thank you

Comment: @Mahammadhusain kadiwala I am waiting for your kind solution. Thank you

Comment: @Mahammadhusain kadiwala I'll check it this afternoon or tonight carefully. It's nearly dawn here. Now I'm going to sleep. At first glance everything seems ok your answer, thank you. Meanwhile I voted for you. I'll try the code this afternoon and let you know. See you after several hours. Thank you

Comment: @MrE I would like also read your kind solution :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#views.py

```
def DemoView(request):
  color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black","Orange")
  message =''
  if request.method =="POST":
    picked = request.POST.get('color')
    if picked == 'Red':
      message = "<<< You chose red"
      print(message)
    elif picked == 'Blue':
        message = "<<< You chose blue"
    elif picked == 'Black':
        message = "<<< You chose black"
    else:
        message = "<<< Oh no, you chose orange"
  context = {'message':message,'color_choices':color_choices}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

## HTML code

```html
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form action="" method="POST" novalidate class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="color" class="form-select" >
          {% for i in color_choices %}
          <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="msg" cols="30" rows="10">{{message}}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I'll check it this afternoon or tonight carefully. It's nearly dawn here. Now I'm going to sleep. At first glance everything seems ok your answer, thank you. Meanwhile I voted for you. I'll try the code this afternoon and let you know. See you after several hours. Thank you

Comment: PART 1: Being still awake, I tested your code. I noticed that when I click on the Submit button, the page reloads (disappears and after half a second it reappears). I don't know how to use Django very well, but Flask a little. The code I posted in my question I had previously used with Flask and the page would not reload (or at any rate not disappear and then reappear after half a second). With Flask when I clicked Submit, the page didn't reload. Why in Flask the page didn't reload and in Django it does? Does it depend on the code I had written in hmtl?

Comment: PART 2: I've updated my question and below is the html I used to be using in Flask. Could it be due to this? Is there another way to prevent the page from reloading? (excluding Javascript). Why in Flask the page didn't reload and in Django it does? If there is another way, could you edit your question and add the code of a second way please? Thank you

Comment: PART 3: Could it be due to some redirection or action in <form action=""? My site opens the index.html page, from which I open the login.html page. After logging into login.html, the site opens the home.html page (in which I inserted the forms) if the login is correct. The address of when I view the forms is http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ and when I click Submit I still get http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ (rightfully so). The forms are in home.html. I don't know if this information is important to solve the page reload

Comment: PART 4. Looking closely at your code, I thought the problem was type=submit, which I replaced with type=button. But nothing happens. Maybe you have to use the click event, I don't know. Could you review your code please? Thank you